# map_location_picker: Map is not loading

Tags: android, flutter, google-maps

I'm trying to work with the flutter package [map_location_picker: ^0.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/map_location_picker)

This seems to work but the map is not show, even if I change the location

Can anyone helps me to make it work well?

**My code**

```
 LocationResult result = await showLocationPicker(
                      context,
                      "AIzaSyAs5ElN",
                      initialCenter: LatLng(_userLat, _userLong),
                      myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                      layersButtonEnabled: true,
                      countries: ['BF'],
                      language: 'fr',
                      hintText: 'Rechercher une adresse',
                      requiredGPS: true,
                      automaticallyAnimateToCurrentLocation: true,
                      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.bestForNavigation,
                      resultCardAlignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                      // mapStylePath: 'assets/mapStyle.json',
                    );
```

Here is how it actually look like

[image]

> flutter doctor
>
> [✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.3, on macOS 12.4 21F79 darwin-x64,
> localefr-BF) [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
> (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1) [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
> (Xcode 13.4.1) [✓] Chrome - develop for the web [✓] Android Studio
> (version 2021.2) [✓] VS Code (version 1.68.1) [✓] Connected device (3
> available) [✓] HTTP Host Availability
>
> • No issues found!

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The code below should be placed between  and  in the AndroidManifest.xml and not elsewhere

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
           android:value="MAP API KEY HERE"/>
```